# Cloudwatch Evidently on iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, evidently

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve Evidently feature flags in an iOS app. I did create the flag on AWS console and also an UnAuthenticated IAM Role to use with Evidently.

I have so far the Cognito authentication code:

```
// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
   let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1, identityPoolId:"us-east-1:xxx")
   let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
   AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

BUT the iOS SDK does not seem to include Evidently or at least I could not find it.

Any advice or examples on how to call Evidently?

Can Evidently even be used with iOS?

There seems to be APIs to call on Evidently REST api (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatchevidently/latest/APIReference/API_GetFeature.html)
but I did not find any example on how to use it with all the authentication flow. Also cannot figure out if it would be possible to authenticate with the Cognito SDK and then call the Evidently using the API.